# Counterexample Poincaré Inequality for $H_0^1$ in 2D

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Is there any counterexample to the Poincaré inequality
$$\int_\Omega|f|^2dx\leq C(\Omega)\int_\Omega|\nabla f|^2dx $$
for $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, $C(\Omega)>0$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$?

I know that this is true for any bounded $\Omega$ and I am looking for an counterexample which changes the assumption of boundedness but features $f\in H^1_0$. Optimally it is easy to compute...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39141/version-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-inequality

Comment: Let me add the following: If the domain is bounded in one coordiante direction (i.e. $|x\cdot \nu|<C$ for some normed vector $\nu$ and every $x\in\Omega$), then the Poincare inequality still holds. The proof is essentially the same as the one for the Poincare inequality you stated

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Thanks for the additional comment. This is new to me - I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that on $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2$ we find that $H^1_0(\Omega)=H^1(\Omega)$. To see that such a constant $C$ can not exists think of the following example.
Consider the functions $u_k:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$ u_k(x) := \chi_{\{[-k,k]\}}(x) + (k+1 - |x|)\chi_{\{[-(k+1),-k]\cup[k,k+1]\}}(x)$$

and simply make them rotational symmetric to get a $2-D$-example. Note that the function is "large" on a large part of the domain and the gradient is only large on a small part of the domain. Let us only consider the $1-D$ case from now on.

We write down the Integrals of the poincare inequality and want to show that there is some $C$ depending only on the domain such that
$$2k \leq \int_\Omega f^2 \leq C \int_\Omega |\nabla f|^2 =  2C $$
holds for every $k$. This is impossible.

Comment: No comments so far? Is my answer unsatisfactory?

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Just missed the notification and got back to the question right now.